# Unresolved Reference [KOTLIN]

Tags: android, kotlin, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to send a variable from one class to another class created in a different package but it keeps telling me that i have unresolved reference and i can't import the variable.

This is where i try to call the variables (The ones i'm talking about are "KEY_ACCOUNT_LIST_CHANGED" and "KEY_CURRENT_ACCOUNT_CHANGED"):

```
if (requestCode == ACTION_MANAGE_ACCOUNTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!!.getBooleanExtra(
        AccountsManagementActivity.KEY_ACCOUNT_LIST_CHANGED,
        false
    )
) {

    // current account has changed
    if (data.getBooleanExtra(AccountsManagementActivity.KEY_CURRENT_ACCOUNT_CHANGED, false)) {
        account = drawerViewModel.getCurrentAccount(this)
        // Refresh dependencies to be used in selected account
        initDependencyInjection()
        restart()
    }
```

As you can see, they are declaired at the class "AccountsManagementActivity" which is build this way:

```
abstract class AccountsManagementActivity : FileActivity(), AccountsManagementAdapter.AccountAdapterListener, AccountManagerCallback<Boolean> {

    val KEY_CURRENT_ACCOUNT_CHANGED = "CURRENT_ACCOUNT_CHANGED"
    val KEY_ACCOUNT_LIST_CHANGED = "ACCOUNT_LIST_CHANGED"

....
```

I've tried to delete the "abstract" from AccountsManagementActivity and then in the other class make this call:

```
val accountsManagementActivity = AccountsManagementActivity()
```

but the app crashes

i hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to access variables like that you need to make them static.
For kotlin you need

```
companion object {
    val KEY_CURRENT_ACCOUNT_CHANGED = "CURRENT_ACCOUNT_CHANGED"
    val KEY_ACCOUNT_LIST_CHANGED = "ACCOUNT_LIST_CHANGED"
}
```

now you can access them like this

```
AccountsManagementActivity.KEY_ACCOUNT_LIST_CHANGED
```